# How to find confidence sets for a bunch of regression functions?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, predictive-modeling, confidence

Unlike confidence intervals where we are interested in indicating a range of beta values in which the true parameter lies 95% of all times, I would like to understand how confidence sets are constructed for a bunch of different functions which are trying to predict the same outcome.

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: What is a confidence set? Can you define it?

Comment: A set of functions which lie within the specified y-range.